# Assignment (chatbot)

Tags: python, string, random

My task:

> Create a menu option which makes the bot print the date and time of today, a random mood, an integer and a float. Everything should be put together in a string sentence.

This is what I have got so far which I think I should use. The problem is I'm not certain how to put it all together.

```
def dateandfeels():
    """
    docstring
    """
    today = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    time1 = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    whole = int(15)
    float1 = float(0.056)
    mood = ['happy', 'sad', 'moody', 'pythonic']
    moody = (random.choice(mood))

    print("""Today is {today}. Time is {time1}. My number of choice is {whole}
    and my float of choice is {float1}. Also I'm feeling a bit {moody} today""")
```

If anyone could provide some help or tips on how to get this going I would be grateful.

Comment: See https://pyformat.info/

Comment: If you're using Python 3.6+ you can use an f-string: just put `f` before the quotes of your output string: `print(f"""Today is {today}. etc""")`

Comment: BTW, I _think_ your assignment requires you to generate a _random_ int and a _random_ float. But you should check that with your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you need something like this, right?

```
import time
import random
def dateandfeels():
  """
  docstring
  """
  toPrint="";
  today = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
  toPrint+=today;
  time1 = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
  toPrint+=" "+time1;
  whole = int(15)
  toPrint+= " "+str(whole)
  float1 = float(0.056)
  toPrint+=" "+str(float1);
  mood = ['happy', 'sad', 'moody', 'pythonic']
  toPrint+=" "+''.join(mood);
  moody = str((random.choice(mood)))
  toPrint+=" "+moody;
  print("Here print the string: \n")
  print (toPrint+"\n")
  print("Here use printf like to print all variables: \n")
  print ("Today is %s. Time is %s. My number of choice is %d and my float of choice is %f. Also I'm feeling a bit %s today" %(today,time1,whole,float1,moody))

dateandfeels()
```

First I add all variables into string and the print it and the other way I did it hust to print any variable with its type, is this right?